# How do I keep line breaks from Email when using extract_msg?

Tags: python

I'm using Matthew Walker's extract-msg module, (which I love); however, I'm having an issue with the msg.body removing the line breaks when posting to Microsoft TFS (TFSAPI module). As of now the subject of the email comes over with the signature, and previous replies which makes it hard to read at times. Each email is different so I'm not sure how I can splice out what's not needed.

I'm not sure if it's the TFSAPI or extract-msg module that is causing the issue.

Is it possible to keep the line breaks and formatting from the original email or close to it? Below is an example of what is displaying in TFS.

[image]

```
def e2tfs():
    '''Extract details from emails and assign those fields to TFS Support Ticket'''
    associate = form.getvalue('associate')
    i=1
    for file in os.listdir():
        src = file
        msg = extract_msg.Message(src)
        msg_sender = msg.sender
        msg_date = msg.date
        msg_subj = msg.subject
        msg_message = msg.body
        i+=1

        #Associate the emails details to the TFS fields
        fields = {'System.Title' : 'E2TFS: {}'.format(msg_subj),
                  'Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Symptom': 'body: {}' .format(msg_message),
                  'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps': 'TBD',
                  'Regions.Custom.DocumentationArea': 'Unknown',
                  'Regions.Custom.Application': 'nCino',
                  'Regions.Custom.Channel': 'Email',
                  'Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.FoundInEnvironment': 'Production',
                  'Regions.Custom.ImpactedAssociate': 'Sender: {}'.format(msg_sender),
                  'Regions.Custom.Associate_Role': 'ALL USERS',
                  'Regions.Custom.BusinessGroupsImpacted2': 'All Business Groups',
                  'AFS.phase.dev': 'ALL USERS',
                  'Regions.Custom.PriorityCustomField': 'High',
                  'Regions.Custom.CaseOwner': associate,
                  'History': 'Ticket created from email sent directly to CBG Level II Support on  {}'.format(msg_date)
                  }      


        client.create_workitem('Support Ticket', fields=fields)

        query_tfs = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] FROM workitems WHERE [System.CreatedDate] = @today AND [System.CreatedBy] = @me AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Support Ticket'"


        wiql = client.run_wiql(query_tfs)


        # Get all found workitems
        workitems = wiql.workitems
        tfs_number = workitems[-1]['Id']
```

Comment: Are you sure the mail had line breaks? It's common to send email with an entire paragraph in one line, and depend on the mail client to wrap it.

Comment: @Barmar Unless I'm missing something, I have tested myself by creating an email and typing out the text and hitting enter button a few times and adding more text; however, when I see the finished result it's just one long line of text. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can convert the email message body to html format and update to azure devops. I tested with [workitem update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). And it recognize html format

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT The email coming in is in html format. It looks like it's more of a carriage return issue I think. Still trying to find the best resolve. Do you happen to have an example using workitem update api? I'm somewhat new to coding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @MichaelJackson did you check out below script, how did it go?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I haven't because I'm not familiar with Powershell. I'm somewhat new to Python so I'm still learning. Also, my connection is with TFS and not Azure. We will be migrating to Azure in April but for now we are still on TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example in powershell script to update workitem `description` fields with [workitem update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

You can also refer to other examples in other programming languages in the [Get Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) page

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}_/apis/wit/workitems/{workitem id}?api-version=5.1"

$body = '[
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "value": "<p>This is a H1 header<br/>This is a H2 header</p>"
    }
]'

$connectionToken="<PAT>"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result7 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```